# Call to a member function fetch() on integer in

Tags: php, pdo

I have a problem with a simple pdo query here the query:

```
$NU=$connection->exec("SELECT COUNT(ID) AS Total FROM USERS");
$Result=$NU->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['Total'];
echo "$Result";
```

Since I have no params to bind in the query is correct to use `exec` without `prepare`, and how can I fix this problem? (`Call to a member function fetch() on integer in` )

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exec()` method only returns the number of rows effected. You probably want to use `query()` instead.

```
$NU=$connection->query("SELECT COUNT(ID) AS Total FROM USERS");
$Result=$NU->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['Total'];
echo "$Result";
```

The `query()` statement will execute a single query and return a `PDOStatement` object you can fetch from or `false` on failure.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `query` http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php , then you'll have a object with results you can work with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$NU = $connection->query("SELECT COUNT(ID) AS Total FROM USERS");

$result = $NU->fetch();
echo $result['Total'];
```

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is not `exec` but `prepare`. From the PHP doc: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
```